# Even onmousedown and onmouseout in Android or Ipad gadget

Tags: javascript, touchscreen, onmouseout, onmousedown, onmouseup

I am trying to make a simple music instrument with JS. The library used is [Pizzicato.js](https://alemangui.github.io/pizzicato/). HTML element for triggering the sound is a button with `onclick`, `onmousedown`, `onmouseup` and `onmouseout` events. The first event is only for testing the function `play()` and `stop()` from `Pizzicato` object. And later the two events are used for more convenient interaction.

Following script is tested in notebook and also worked in Android or IPad gadgets

```
function demoToggleSound() {
    var eout = document.getElementById("scriptResult");
    eout.innerHTML = "";

    var sineWave = new Pizzicato.Sound({ 
        source: 'wave', 
        options: {
                frequency: 880
        }
    });

    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = "Play";
    eout.appendChild(btn);
    btn.addEventListener("click", btnClick);

    function btnClick() {
        var t = event.target;
        if(t.innerHTML == "Play") {
            t.innerHTML = "Stop";
            sineWave.play();
        } else {
            t.innerHTML = "Play";
            sineWave.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

for `click` event, but for `onmousedown` , `onmouseup` and `onmouseout` events in the followiing script

```
function demoSimpleInstrument() {
    var eout = document.getElementById("scriptResult");
    eout.innerHTML = "";

    var baseFrequency = 880;
    var sineWave = new Pizzicato.Sound({ 
        source: "wave",
        options: {
                //frequency: baseFrequency
        }
    });

    var ratio = [1/1, 9/8, 5/4, 4/3, 3/2, 5/3, 15/8, 2/1];
    var label = ["C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C"];
    for(var i = 0; i < ratio.length; i++) {
        var b = document.createElement("button");
        b.innerHTML = label[i];
        b.id = i;
        eout.appendChild(b);
        b.addEventListener("mousedown", playSound);
        b.addEventListener("mouseup", stopSound);
        b.addEventListener("mouseout", stopSound);
    }

    function playSound() {
        var t = event.target;
        var f = baseFrequency * ratio[t.id];
        sineWave.frequency = f;
        sineWave.play();
    }

    function stopSound() {
        sineWave.stop();
    }
}
```

it does not work. Should I change `onmousedown`, `onmouseup` and `onmouseout` events in gadgets with touchscreen?

Comment: [touchstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Events/touchstart) would be the touch-screen equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4830296/jeff). And by adding following lines of script

```
b.addEventListener("touchstart", playSound);
b.addEventListener("touchend", stopSound);
```

It does work, but unfortunately only in Google Chrome and not in Safari.

Comment: Thank, was looking for few hours for onMouseDown / Up events for react on android, and couldn't find anything on it, seen it implemented though and working, but couldn't figure out what to do, but this touchStart work like charm, though only for mobile devices, but its onTouchStart. Check touch events --> for info, for anyone still looking
https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html